# Animation - Scale, After Finishing on iphone it jumps away

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, animation, styled-components

I have this problem, I'm trying to work with animations, and everything works as I expect, even in the simulator. But the problem occurs if I take a physical device (Iphone). At that point the background zooms in, and after the animation is done, the div jumps to the left, as seen in the attached video.  [Video](https://streamable.com/rfbvpp)

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Thanks

This problem only takes place on physical equipment and does not appear in emulators.

The problem occurs on iphone, both on safari and chromium browsers.

Repository code:
[Code](https://github.com/tmp-game-dev/minting_page)

I expect the div to stay in the position in which it starts to load when zooming, as shown by the emulators and desktop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by applying `will-change: transform;`

Comment: As you can see in the [tour], Stack Overflow maintains a very strict separation between questions and answers; what you've posted is an answer (and I've edited it to make it *only* an answer). This is not the place to ask a follow-up question. If you have a follow-up question, please ask a new question. (And watch your language! No expletives allowed here, as this is a professional website.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).